# Не могу понять результат выражения

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>  
main() 
{     int nextnum, y = 2, n = 3;     
      nextnum = (y + n++)*6;     
      printf("Result = %d\n", nextnum);     
}
```

Почему результат выдает 30 вместо 36?

Comment: Так там постинкремент. Вначале складываем 2 и 3. Но лучше такой код не писать

Comment: @МихаилФленов, тезка автора Библии Delphi, C# и других книг?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верно выдает:

(2+3) * 6 = 5 * 6 = 30

n++ - это постфиксный инкремент, он сначала возвращает значение n, а **потом** его увеличивает

Comment: Понял спасибо ..

Answer (score 2):

Хотите 36? Используйте префиксный инкремент:

```
nextnum = (y + ++n)*6;
```

https://ideone.com/TjTJBA